# How to load fancyimpute in python?

Tags: python

While loading the from fancyimpute import KNN, I'm getting the following error. How can I load this library and remove the error ?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-082daf1fc59c> in <module>
----> 1 from fancyimpute import KNN

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fancyimpute'
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to install it with pip `pip install fancyimpute`

Comment: Have you installed it first?

Answer (score 0):

When importing with a simple `import LIBRARY` statement, python checks 2 places.

1. The directory that your file is in.
2. Your lib folder where you installed python. A quick google search will tell you where that is depending on your operating system.

In your case, the module `fancyimpute` was probably incorrectly installed. They do not support anaconda so you must install using pip.

To solve this, simply enter the following commands in your command line:

```
python -m pip uninstall fancyimpute
python -m pip install fancyimpute
```

Don't worry if the first doesn't work, it's there to potentially clean up a improper installation.